# How to equalize the two columns in the last page INSIDE the IEEEbiography enviroment

Tags: spacing, page-breaking, two-column, ieeetran, ieee-style

I'd like to make the two columns of the last page of equal length but starting the new column INSIDE the `IEEEbiography` environment. I have four authors in the last page, the second one has a long biography than the other three, therefore, with `\newpage` after the second author, the left column looks longer than the right one. You can think of the layout as a square followed by a long rectangle on the left and two squares on the right. So, I basically, need to break the line and start the new column INSIDE the `IEEEbiography` environment of the second author (the rectangle). When I use `\newpage` inside `IEEEbiography`, I got an error message "Tex capacity exceeded, sorry". When I use `\pagebreak`, the layout messes up: a huge white space is created in the left column between the first and second authors, and the third and fourth authors go to a new page. I tried many solutions on the forum for similar questions, specifically, `\balance`, `\newpage`, `\pagebreak`, `\vfill`, `\flushend`, `\multicolumns`, but none of them has worked out correctly as I want.

```
\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{author1.eps}}]%
{Author1} received the ...
line 2
line 3
line 4
\end{IEEEbiography}

\begin{IEEEbiography}
[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{author2.eps}}]%
{Author2} is ...
line 2 
line 3 
line 4 
% New paragraph 
line 5 
line 6 
== > a break of this column should be here to have two equal columns \\
line 7 
line 8 
\end{IEEEbiography}

\newpage\noindent

\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{author3.eps}}]%
{Author3} received the ...
line 2
line 3
line 4
\end{IEEEbiography}

\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,clip,keepaspectratio]{author4.eps}}]%
{Author4} received the ...
line 2
line 3
line 4
\end{IEEEbiography}
```

Comment: A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should never balance biographies yourself unless you are not going to submit this work to a journal. The publication office will take care of this and making them roughly equal will be enough.

But a terrible example is putting a dummy no photo bibliograhy if this is a burning issue. There are more hacks needed if you use table of contents but this is already an ugly solution.

```
\documentclass[final]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{mwe} %<- For dummy images
\usepackage[nopar]{kantlipsum} %<- For dummy text
\begin{document}

\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,keepaspectratio]{example-image-a}}]%
{First Author} received the \kant[1]
\end{IEEEbiography}

\vspace{-1cm}

\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,keepaspectratio]{example-image-b}}]%
{Second Author} received the \kant[1-3] And then bla bla happened typical stuff and some filler words
\end{IEEEbiography}

\enlargethispage{-5.6cm}\vfill

\begin{IEEEbiographynophoto}{\relax}\unskip
then we continue \kant[4]
\end{IEEEbiographynophoto}

\vspace{-0.5cm}

\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,keepaspectratio]{example-image-c}}]%
{Third Author} received the \kant[3]
\end{IEEEbiography}

\vspace{-0.5cm}

\begin{IEEEbiography}[{\includegraphics[width=1in,height=1.25in,keepaspectratio]{example-image}}]%
{Fourth Author} received the \kant[4]
\end{IEEEbiography}\vfill
\end{document}
```

[image]