# How to split biography with IEEE Access template

Tags: ieeeaccess

`IEEEtran` latex class defines `IEEEbiographynophoto` that helps you to split a biography between two columns. A nice example here:
[how-to-equalize-the-two-columns-in-the-last-page-inside-the-ieeebiography-enviro](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132175/how-to-equalize-the-two-columns-in-the-last-page-inside-the-ieeebiography-enviro)

I change the document template from `IEEEtran` to `ieeeaccess`:

```
\documentclass{ieeeaccess}
```

and receive errors:

```
...\test2.tex:18: Undefined control sequence. [\begin{IEEEbiographynophoto}{\relax}]
...\test2.tex:18: LaTeX Error: No counter 'biography' defined. [\begin{IEEEbiographynophoto}{\relax}]
```

I don't think I should be editing cls file. (e.g., inserting biography counter -- that is defined as `IEEEbiography` in `IEEEtran.cls` anyway), am I missing some definition or includes? Furthermore, having that defined, the next error is:

```
Extra \fi. [\begin{IEEEbiographynophoto}{\relax}]
```

Source for class used:
[IEEE Article Templates](https://journals.ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/create-your-ieee-journal-article/authoring-tools-and-templates/tools-for-ieee-authors/ieee-article-templates/)

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Your write-up would appear to refer to `IEEEbiographynophoto`, yet you've also set the `bibliographies` tag. Please clarify.

Comment: Ups, thanks for pointing out! fixed. (I didn't have points to add a new tag "IEEEbiographynophoto", but obviously result was wrong.) Also, behaviour is same with "biographynophoto" as those are defined as same in ieeeaccess.cls. Thus tag "biographynophoto".

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. I've removed the `bibliographies` tag from your posting

Comment: I'm having the exact same error, I hope someone can say what's wrong here.